# Masters' thesis in algorithmic graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I would like some ideas on topics in algorithmic graph theory which would be suitable for a masters' thesis. What sort of problems would be suitable for this level? Because it is at masters' level, no original work is necessarily needed but it can instead be an original comprehensive survey of some area. Thank you

Comment: This is something that should be discussed with professors at your university.

Comment: the profs in my university are in pure mathematics.that's why i have to come up with a topic on my own.

Comment: Did you end up coming up with something?

Comment: @DominicFarolino yes, i analysed linguistic networks of two different languages.